# Append recaptcha message error to rails errors.messages.values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings

I have such code in controller:

```
if verify_recaptcha #verify_recaptcha(:model => @order, :message => "Oh! It's error with reCAPTCHA!") && 
      respond_to do |format|
        if @order.save
          Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
          session[:cart_id] = nil
          OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order, @user).deliver
          UserOrderMailer.user_order_mailer(@order, @user).deliver
          #OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
          pdf_link = generate_pdf(@order)
          link = "  <a href=\"#{pdf_link}\">#{I18n.t(:get_pdf)}</a>"   
          format.html { redirect_to root_url, :notice => (I18n.t(:successful_order_send)+link.to_s).html_safe}

        else
          format.html { render :action => "new", :notice => I18n.t(:error) }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }

        end
      end
    else
      flash[:warning] = I18n.t(:wrong_captcha)
      redirect_to :back 
    end
```

And in form view:

```
  - if @user_vehicle.errors.messages.values.present?
    .warning
      - @user_vehicle.errors.messages.values.each do |msg|       
        - msg.each do  |m|
          %li= m
```

But also in layout i have:

```
- if flash[:warning]
              .warning
                = flash[:warning]
            - if flash[:notice]
              .notice
                = flash[:notice]
```

I want to know, how can i append recaptcha fail error to errors.messages.values list of error's and display in same div and with li as i do for model validation messages?
How can i see as one more li item recaptcha message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if verify_recaptcha
  ...
else
  @user_vehicle.errors.add(:base, I18n.t(:wrong_captcha))
end
```